# How to use refiners in search?

Tags: search, refiner

I'm using Microsoft Search Server Express 2010 and need to implement search with refiners through the `search.asmx` web service. Currently I'm trying to execute following query:

```
<QueryPacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Query">
  <Query>
    <SupportedFormats>
      <Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document</Format>
    </SupportedFormats>
    <Context>
      <QueryText>us</QueryText>
    </Context>
    <Properties>
      <Property name="Author" />
    </Properties>
    <EnableStemming>true</EnableStemming>
    <EnableSpellCheck>false</EnableSpellCheck>
    <IncludeRelevantResults>true</IncludeRelevantResults>
    <Range>
      <Count>20</Count>
    </Range>
    <IncludeRefinementResults>
      <Refiners>
        <Refiner>author</Refiner>
      </Refiners>
    </IncludeRefinementResults>
  </Query>
</QueryPacket>
```

against the `QueryEx` method. I'm getting the `RelevantResults` table, but no `RefinementResults` is present in the DataSet.

Is it possible to use refiners with the search.asmx web service? If so then how to do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563775.aspx), IncludeRefinementResults, Refiners, and Refiner elements apply only to FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint.